# Where has development? and build? gone in middleman v4

Tags: environment, middleman

In version 3.0 of middleman, you've been able to use the variables `development?` and `build?` in templates. In version 4.0 these variables no longer exist.

How do I identify which environment middleman is currently running in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Middleman v4.0 uses a new method of identifying which environment it is currently running in. This is because you can now have more than two environments.

Old syntax:

```
<% if development? %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

New syntax:

```
<% if config[:environment].eql?(:development) %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can just do

```
<% if development? %> ... <% end %>
```

Reference https://github.com/middleman/middleman/blob/48c97b22ff25e22a2533fb5b4128337b5a97e080/CHANGELOG.md#418